# Django: How to do full-text search for Japanese (multibyte strings) in Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

It is possible to create an index for searching using SearchVector, but
However, Japanese words are not separated by spaces, and the full-text search does not work properly.
How can I perform full-text search in Japanese (multi-byte character strings)?

I thought about implementing a search engine such as ElasticSearch, but other problems came up.
If possible, I would like to do FTS with Postgres.

```py
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    search = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search"])]

# update search column
Post.objects.update(search=SearchVector('title'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Pgroonga](https://github.com/pgroonga/pgroonga) Postgres extension for fulltext search in all languages. It is used by the Zulip project with amazing results.